# How to de-serialize a raw array of arrays from REST response using Springboot RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, jackson-databind

I am using SpringBoot RestTemplate to consume a REST API. The response body consists of an array of arrays, with each of the nested arrays having a key value pair, similar to this:

```
[
    ["michael",0.9227975606918335],
    ["frank",0.888996958732605],
    ["christian",0.887883722782135]
]
```

This JSON structure isn't ideal, of course, but I have to work with it. I would like to deserialize this response to a Java object that has one field (2-dim array).

The API is called like this:

```
GetResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, GetResponse.class);
```

The Java class structure looks like this (all annotated with Lombok's @NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor, @Getter, @Setter):

```
    public class GetResponse {
        @JsonProperty
        private NamesArray[] data;
    }

    public class NamesArray {
        @JsonProperty
        private KeyValuePair[] data;
    }

    public class KeyValuePair {
        @JsonProperty
        private String key;

        @JsonProperty
        private float rating;
    }
```

This should work, but I keep getting this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type 
[class com.mypackage.Client$GetResponse] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot 
deserialize value of type `com.mypackage.Client$GetResponse` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Cannot deserialize value of type `com.mypackage.Client$GetResponsesponse` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
```

Any ideas what the required class structure would look like? Am I missing a Jackson annotation anywhere? Note that I do get a response so the problem is clearly with the Deserialization.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map your response to `KeyValuePair[].class` not to `GetResponse.class` and add `@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` annotation to KeyValuePair class.

Something like this should work:

**KeyValuePair class:**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public static class KeyValuePair {
   private String key;
   private float rating;
}
```

**Response:**

```java
KeyValuePair[] response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, KeyValuePair[].class);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because `@JsonFormat` cannot be used to annotate a class. I tried to created a wrapper class for the response object with a single property of type `KeyValuePair[]` and annotate this property with `@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)`, but this doesn't work either (same error msg). Also, I tried to use an array of this response object, but same problem.

Comment: Made some progress now: 1) The response needs to be mapped to a 2-dim array, like this: `KeyValuePair[][] response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, KeyValuePair[][].class);`. Because this is just the structure of the JSON response. and 2) There is still something weird, because there are two KeyValuePair objects being constructed for each of the actual pairs in the response. This is because each KVP is a 1-dim array of size 2 and 1 KVP gets constructed per item in the array: the first one with a String, the 2nd with a float. I guess this is because the mapping from Array to KVP doesn't work.